# Dynamic Web Project (Eclipse)-->HTTP STATUS 404 Error

Tags: java, eclipse, jsp, http, http-status-code-404

I'm making my first java web application following a tutorial on youtube. It is a Dynamic Web Application and the code I've written so far is fairly simple but I'm having an issue with HTTP 404 error.

My web.xml appears as followed:`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0">
  <display-name>PuzzleProject</display-name>
  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.htm</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.htm</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.jsp</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>
  <servlet>
    <description> </description>
    <display-name>MyServlet</display-name>
    <servlet-name>MyServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>BackEnd</servlet-class>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>MyServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/MyServlet</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

`

My Index.jsp:

```
 `<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8"
    pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"     "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>

<h1>Welcome, please enter a bunch of words.</h1>
<input type="text" name="words" value="">

<form action = "MyServlet">
    <input type="submit" value="Send" />
</form>


</body>
</html>
```

`MyServlet.java:`

```
package BackEnd;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;

import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

/**
 * Servlet implementation class MyServlet
 */
public class MyServlet extends HttpServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    /**
     * Default constructor. 
     */
    public MyServlet() {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
     */
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        // response.getWriter().append("Served at: ").append(request.getContextPath());
        PrintWriter print = response.getWriter();
        String string = "My Name Is Steven";
        print.println(string);
    }

    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
     */
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        doGet(request, response);
    }

}
```

`

Can someone please tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Ahem... What is your request url?

Comment: You're probably missing the context root, that eclipse default's to the project name (spaces are converted to "_").

Comment: Hope you have not spelled `index.jsp` with `I` in capital letter and in your `web.xml` it must be full path of servlet `<servlet-class>Backend.MyServlet</servlet-class>`